# Assign a classname to the selected element and the correct one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume I have a JSON-file that looks like this one:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "question": "What's 1+1",
      "answers": [
        {
          "text": "3",
          "correct": false
        },
        {
          "text": "2",
          "correct": true
        }
      ]
     }
   ]
}
```

In my code I am iterating over these answers and rendering a button for each. Each button also receives a click-handler like beneath. What I'd like to happen when you click a button, is that if it's the correct one, I should assign it a *(correct)* class. But if it's the wrong one, I will assign it another *(wrong)* class, but **still** show which was the correct one.

```
const handleClick = answer => {
  // How would I implement this logic?
 }

const App = ({ data }) => {

return (
  <div>
   {data.answers.map(answer => (
    <button onClick={() => handleClick(answer)}>{answer.text}</button>
   ))}
  </div>
 )
}
```

I tried to create a state variable to the button that was clicked. Then compare it against the parameter that was passed through the onclick handler.

Comment: So, You just want dynamic class in button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain a `selectedAnswer` state that you set once you select an answer. You can then decide to show the `correct` class when mapping if the current answer's `.correct` property is `true` and the `incorrect` class if it is `false`, this class is stord in `classType` below. Since you only want to show these classes once you've selected an answer, you can conditionally add the class if:

- You have selected an answer (ie `selectedAnnswer` has a value)

AND

- Add the class if the currently mapped answer is correct OR the current answer is your selected answer

See example below:

```js
const {useState} = React;
const App = ({ data }) => {
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState();
  const handleClick = answer => {
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
  }

  return (
    <div>
     {data.answers.map(answer => {
        const classType = answer.correct ? "correct" : "incorrect";
        const showClass = selectedAnswer && (answer.correct || selectedAnswer === answer);
        return <button
          key={answer.text}
          className={showClass && classType}
          onClick={() => handleClick(answer)}>{answer.text}</button>
     })}
    </div>
  );
}


const obj = { "data": [ { "question": "What's 1+1", "answers": [ { "text": "3", "correct": false }, { "text": "2", "correct": true }, { "text": "1", "correct": false } ] } ] }
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App data={obj.data[0]} />);
```

```css
.correct {background: lime;}
.incorrect {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! Really thorough answer. Never thought about implementing the logic within the map function. I just made some different stuff in the handleClick function (which perhaps could have been solved there too), but this made more sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonJonzzon No worries! (nice first question btw) :)

Answer (score 1):

For Dynamic classname try this,

```
const App = ({ data }) => {

return (
 <div>
  {data.answers.map(answer => (
   <button classname={answer.correct ? 'correct-class' : 'wrong-class'`} onClick={() => handleClick(answer)}>{answer.text}</button>
  ))}
 </div>
)}
```

Comment: This will always display correct/wong classes on all items and doesn't happen onClick

Comment: What exactly you want can you explain me?

Comment: Also for more complex logic you can use a small library named clsx, it's great!

Comment: Imagine you have 4 buttons. One of these are the correct one. If you press the one that is correct, it get's the "correct" classname. However, if you press a button that isn't correct, it get's the "incorrect" classname and the one that was correct, gets the "correct" classname.

Comment: @PriyenMehta The desired behavior is explained in the question. OP is looking to add the classes when a click occurs, whereas this doesn't do that. It just adds the classes as soon as the buttons are displayed. See my answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74558433/5648954)) for my interpretation

Answer (score -1):

```js
 const App = ({ data }) => {

    return (
      <div>
       {data.answers.map(answer => (
        <button 
         className={`${answer.correct ? "correct" : "wrong"} other 
         classes `} 
         onClick={() => handleClick(answer)}>{answer.text}
        </button>
       ))}
      </div>
     )
    }
```

Comment: OP is looking to add the classes when a click occurs, whereas this doesn't do that. It just adds the classes as soon as the buttons are displayed. This also adds the class to _all_ buttons, not just the incorrect one that was clicked. Please also check other answers before posting, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74558114/5648954) has the same code but was posted much earlier. In addition, when answering a question, please add some explanation instead of code-only answers, that will help OP, future readers as it will improve the overall quality of your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).